Non-zero element in diagonal of cofactor matrix of symmetric 0-1 matrix with non-zero determinant, zero diagonal and odd number of rows
Is the following statement correct?
Let $A$ be a symmetric 0-1 matrix with non-zero determinant, all diagonal elements equal to 0 and an odd number of rows. The diagonal of the cofactor matrix of $A$ contains a non-zero element.
I verified this statement with a computer for millions of matrices $A$ and it seems to be correct, but I am unable to prove it.

you might replace cofactor matrix of $A$ by $A^{-1}$, right?

That is correct. You can replace the cofactor matrix of $A$ by $A^{-1}$.
